# How to I write code to test code from another class?

Tags: java, string, testing, reverse

So I'm supposed to write code to test a method from a test class however I'm totally lost. I guess I'm just confused whether I have to right regular code such as for loops or if I'm able to do it another way. I'm new to java and it's causing me a ton of trouble!

Here is one such method from the interface I have to test:

```
    // Returns a reversed version of the specified string,
    // which can contain any ASCII character.
    // For example, returns "edcba" for "abcde" 
    public String reverseString(String s);
```

Comment: Would you like to try something called JUnit or some other framework? It provides you with a standard to test the code in your projects.

Comment: There are any number of good ways to test code, but you'll have better luck asking your instructor to clarify what they expect. It's unlikely we'll be able to tell you what they're looking for.

Comment: Perhaps the approach is: [Red, Green, Refactor](http://quintagroup.com/services/python/test-driven-development). To write the test code, you could stub out a concrete class that does _not_ work but lets the test code compile and run, getting a failing result. That's progress!

Answer (score 1):

A tool you could use to test code is the `assert` keyword:

```
String str = "Hello World!";

assert str.equals("42") : "Not 42!"; // will throw an exception
```

`assert exp1 : exp2` will throw a `java.lang.AssertionError` if *exp1* evaluates to `false`. *exp2*, which is optional, will be the message of that error.

i.e.:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: Not 42!
```

---

Assertions are not turned on by default however. You need to pass `-ea` as a VM argument when running the program.

```
java <VM args> <Main class name> <program args>
```

e.g.:

```
java -ea Main
```

---

If you don't want to reinvent the wheel however, I would recommend [JUnit](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4) as a testing framework. It has lots of tools to help with writing test code. It's also widely used, so easy to find tutorials about.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is simple: call the method with various parameters and check if the result matches your expectations. A framework like JUnit will help to organise the test code but you can also do without.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a simple test**:

```
String test = "abcde";
String reverse = reverseString(test);

if (reverse.equals("edcba"))
{
    // test passed
}
else
{
    // test failed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. You need to call the method by doing something like:

```
System.out.println(reverseClass.reverseString("Whatever String You Like"));
```

and you also need to make your reverse string method static.
If you see in your console your expected result your method works.

Comment: Usually, the test would also check for the correctness of the result. The manual inspection becomes unpractical if the number of tests increases.